# AndroidInterface object is not available in javascript even if I have written addJavascriptInterface(this, "AndroidInterface"); in MainActivity class

Tags: java, javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

I am using cordova to build web app and javascript/angularjs.
I want to call an android method from javascript to change android config etc.

I have written code like this

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        webView = new WebView(this);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "AndroidInterface");

        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public  void accessFromJS(){
        // some code...
    }
}
```

Now, I access this method from javascript as

```
window.AndroidInterface.accessFromJS();
```

but, I'm getting error in angularjs as

```
accessFromJS() of 'undefined'.
```

i.e. `AndroidInterface` object is not available in javascript.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I haven't worked with Cordova in some time, but are you *really* sure that you are supposed to be creating your own `WebView`? I mean, that's kinda what Cordova does for you, and yours will never be used, as it is not put on the screen anywhere.

Comment: @CommonsWare, thanks for reply...but I am unable to understand how to access cordova's webview.

Comment: A Google search on `(cordova OR phonegap) android webview addjavascriptinterface` turns up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699500/how-to-call-native-function-from-cordova-3-x FWIW.

Comment: I have gone through this thread, but i couldn't understand how appView variable is created. because, I'm unable to call setJavascriptEnabled on appView.

Comment: `appView` is a `protected` data member of `CordovaActivity`. It used to be a `WebView`, and now is a `CordovaWebView`, probably to improve security. My guess is that they are steering you in the direction of writing a plugin versus just trying to inject stuff ad hoc.

Comment: Well, thanks.. may be I have to write plugin now. Thanks