# androidInterface is not defined. What gives?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I'm seeing a strange javascript exception being triggered by a random user on an android device running chrome. My code contains no reference to anything named androidInterface, and so is not relevant to this question.

**User Agent String:**

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G892A
>   Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
>   Chrome/57.0.2987.132 Mobile Safari/537.36

...which tells me that the user is running Chrome 57 on Android (Nougat)
on a Samsung SM-G892A

The actual error is coming back from window.onError with
`Uncaught ReferenceError: androidInterface is not defined`

Also I track clicks and api calls. This error occurs right as they are loading the page which is just a standard backbone/require setup that is working for a few thousand other customers.

Have you ever seen anything like this? What does it even mean?

Comment: I'm also having a user with this issue, wondering if it's an app they use for filling in passwords on a form.

Comment: do you get a stack trace with the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the UA string, you'll see `wv` which means it's a WebView on Android.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503933/androidinterface-object-is-not-available-in-javascript-even-if-i-have-written-addjavascriptinterface-this-androidinterface-in-mainactivity-class) which made it more clear it's a WebView and then looked at [Chrome User Agent Strings](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#webview_user_agent) to make sure.

Bottom line is that you don't have to change anything because the error is related to the app that implemented the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a search over your node_modules folder to see if you can find a reference to androidInterface.  If you're using third party libraries, it's possible that the reference can be found here.

Comment: While this is not an answer, Please use comment section. Thanks.