# Cordova - How to start / finish specific android java service when I click Html Button?

Tags: cordova, service, native

I am making Hybrid app by using Cordova.

but i am stucked this problem.

When Button in Html is clicked, i want to let specific android Service run.

Does anyone know solution??

Comment: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699500/how-to-call-native-function-from-cordova-3-x

Comment: @HtmlTosin  I know how to call native method from javascript function.  I want to know the way how to start background service using javascript function.