# Calling native Android java code from Cordova WebView (JS) without plugins

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I know this may seem to be a duplicated question from my topic, but none of the solutions of other people's similar question suits me.

I'm trying to create an Android app from Cordova. For some reason, I need to call some native Android java code from Cordova WebView's by a javascript file such as index.js. Most solutions from other people's similar question and Cordova's official documentation suggested creating Android Plugins. Though creating Android Plugins isn't something difficult for me, after reading [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699500/how-to-call-native-function-from-cordova-3-x), I want to do the same thing - simply calling native Android java code from Cordova WebView **without plugins**.

After testing all A/B/C methods in the above article link, I ran into a problem. Though having "android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;" imported, this code:

```
appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");
```

gets this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    appView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "MainActivity");
           ^
symbol:   method addJavascriptInterface(MainActivity,String)
location: variable appView of type CordovaWebView
1 error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Why is this happening? How do I fix this?

Comment: `CordovaWebView` is not a subclass of `WebView` and [does not define that method](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java).

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, but how do I fix this? any workaround?

Comment: and why did the guy of the above article link was able to use that undefined method?

Comment: That material is from 2014. It is now 2019. Perhaps back then `CordovaWebView` was a subclass of `WebView`. Look through the Cordova source code and see how you get the actual `WebView`. It may be as simple as casting `appView` to be a `WebView`.